# How should I connect this switch securely?

Tags: switches, connector

I have a [nifty 22mm pushbutton switch](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3424) with an RGB LED ring light around it. I would like to securely wire this for an application in an outdoor control panel that may get shaken around a bit, so I'm looking for the "right" way to crimp/solder/weld/or otherwise securely connect those poles to wire.

[image: Switch]

- The four large tabs are what the switch actually controls. In my application I'm just running these to an Arduino-type controller so maybe 3.3V or 5V.
- The four little tabs painted different colors are for the RGB LED, also 5V. They appear to be 0.1" apart x 0.3" apart.

Comment: google `push on crimp connector` and look at the pictures

Answer (score 0):

**Why not crimp it?**

Do you have a crimping tool? It can be done perfekly if you have one. Else, you could still do it with a pair of nose pliers.

[image]
[image]

Advantage is that you can remove the connections later.

**Why not solder it**

You cannot remove the connections easily (desoldering will do). You can put in a sleeve into the cable, solder and then secure the solder joint with the sleeve and a hot air gun.

Use the cables coloured in the same way as the RGB pins so that, you don't have to trace it during connection or for debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Forgive me for being dumb ...  the little part you are showing here ... does that get crimped onto the switch itself or does that just slide on and rely on friction? Friction seems like it might come loose with banging around. And also - what kind of connector would stay securely on the thin LED poles?

Comment: @JoelSpolsky You crimp the connector onto a wire and slide it onto the terminal. It's friction fit but it ain't going anywhere. When new, I sometimes can't pull them off without pliers. Contrary to other posts, I think those are solder tabs, not quick connect terminals since the shape isn't quite right (compare your photo vs the one in this answer). But quick connect terminals comes in all sorts of sizes, some very small and if you find one with the right width you can just slide it on and give it a squeeze with some pliers and it won't go anywhere.

Comment: It will slide in but friction is high enough not to come lose.

Comment: for the wide ones it also a a little pip that fits the hole to stop it from shaking loose

Answer (score 0):

This switch has a combination of tabs for a crimp connector, as well as square pins.

Using a "crimp connector" is a three step operation.

First, strip off about 5-10mm or 1/4inch of the insulation from the end of the wire.

Second, insert the exposed wire into the end of the "crimp connector", just in the half covered by the plastic sleeve. Inside, the metal part of the connector is like a metal tube. Using a "crimp tool" (or pliers), gently crush the "plastic sleeve" half of the crimp connector, so that it permanently grips the wire. Do not crush the other half of the connector. Optionally, this half can be soldered for improved reliability, as long as the other half of the connector is kept clear.

Finally, the exposed metal half of the crimp connector (with the rolled-up edges) slips onto the metal tabs of the switch. This is a friction fit, it may require some force to make it fit.

For the square pins (for the LED), or any similar "square pins" test point, my favorite part is TE Connectivity ™ 1-87309-3; Digikey A3007-ND. You can also search "Dupont connector".  Use a little bit of 1/8" heat-shrink tubing for electrical insulation and mechanical strain relief. This particular contact has two tabs that can be folded over the wire, much like the crimp connector. I usually just use a needlenose pliers for these.

Comment: Are those quick connect terminals? I always thought they were solder tabs since they have the same width all the way along their length and do not have tapered leading corners.

Comment: On the adafruit site the contacts are described as spade contacts: "On the back there are 4 metal contacts for the RGB LED ring (one anode and 3 cathodes for each red, green, and blue) and 4 spade contacts for the switches."

Comment: I wouldn't trust that since a spade terminal specifically refers to a fork shaped terminal (as opposed to a quick-connect terminal. I know. The naming surprised me too since I don't think fork looks anything like a spade. I don't know why spade is the official name and not fork.